# How to assign Subdomain for every user in Next Js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, subdomain

Can any one guide me how to create a subdomain for every user in NEXT JS. If a user is registered with a username 'john' and the website domain is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), Then I want to show the profile details of the user at john.example.com.

Comment: I am not really sure what u mean, I know u can do like this: your_domain/users/user1, or any user name u want adter /users/

Comment: I updated the question with additional details for better understanding.

Comment: I am not sure it's possible, you will register a domain for each user?

Comment: No i don't want to register domains, I Just want to access the subdomain and show the relevant data. We can use a wildcard in our DNS to point all subdomains into the app and then i want to access it from there and fetch the relevant data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on a similar application. I don't have the exact answer, I just want to give you a good lead, so you can Google it if you're stuck.

What I know is, that this subdomain you want for each user (john.example.com) is called "multi-tenancy".

Check out these links:

- https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application
- https://userfront.com/guide/auth/multi-tenancy.html
- https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/auth0-overview/create-tenants/multi-tenant-apps-best-practices

If you want to simulate the subdomain behavior on localhost, then you have to edit your /etc/hosts file (Mac) - [link](https://setapp.com/how-to/edit-mac-hosts-file) and for Windows, it is inside the System folder I guess (please google it).

(Below point is not related to the question)

One more thing I would like to share is -- in the case your application has auth, then you have to be careful with the cookies. In my case, I have to maintain the user session on both, the main domain and subdomain. So my cookie domain name is ".localhost" or ".exmaple". Please check the (.) dot in front of localhost.

That's all that I know.